# rails 3 generate controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

i'm learning RoR, and I'm getting an error when generating a controller

> `mitchell@ubuntu:~/Ruby/Website/blog$ rails generate controller posts`

```
/home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /home/mitchell/Ruby/Website/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
from /home/mitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm running Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a command line Javascript interpreter on your development machine.

Install [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and you should be good.

And for the record, this message seems pretty clear:

> Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)

Did you go to that URL and see what it says?

In general, error messages are very helpful things.  When something doesn't work that message is supposed to tell you why, and sometimes even how to fix it.

Comment: now i'm trying to general a model. i figured out the controller. i installed nodejs. its just giving me lists and lists of create this, create that. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You havent described a problem, so how would I ever possibly know "how to fix it"? But even if I did, that would be a great opportunity to make a new question.